# flutter how to create folders to store files in internal storage

Tags: dart, flutter

I was struct in a problem that i have to download pdf or images etc from network and store  them in local storage.i am trying path provider plugin with GetApplicationDocumentDirectory its successfully storing files but not showing in device folder. how to create a directory and store files such as images pdfs etc that are visible to users. how could i achieve that.

thanks for help in advance

Comment: Use getexternal storage method

Answer (score 4):

You can write to the device external storage as shown in the below example code by  creating the folder

Hope it helps

```
class PDFDownloader extends StatefulWidget {
  final String extension;
  final String url;
  final String fileName;

  PDFDownloader(this.url, this.fileName,[this.extension='pdf']);

  @override
  _DownloadAppState createState() => new _DownloadAppState();
}

class _DownloadAppState extends State<PDFDownloader> {

  bool downloading = false;
  String _message;
  var progressString = "";
  Future<Directory> _externalDocumentsDirectory;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //downloadFile();
    checkPer();
//    _bannerAd = createBannerAd()..load();

    super.initState();
  }

  void checkPer() async {
    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 1));
    bool checkResult = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(
        Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
    if (!checkResult) {
      var status = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(
          Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
      //print("permission request result is " + resReq.toString());
      if (status == PermissionStatus.authorized) {
        await downloadFile();
      }
    } else {
      await downloadFile();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scaffold= Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Download"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: downloading
            ? Container(
          height: 120.0,
          width: 200.0,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Downloading File: $progressString",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
            : Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_message ?? 'Please wait!!'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Close'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: scaffold,
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    return new Future.value(!downloading);
  }

  Future<void> downloadFile() async {
    var dio = new Dio();
    var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var knockDir =
    await new Directory('${dir.path}/iLearn').create(recursive: true);
    print(widget.url);
    await dio.download(widget.url, '${knockDir.path}/${widget.fileName}.${widget.extension}',
        onProgress: (rec, total) {
          //print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");

          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              downloading = true;
              progressString = ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
            });
          }
        });
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
        progressString = "Completed";
        _message = "File is downloaded to your SD card 'iLearn' folder!";
      });
    }
    print("Download completed");
  }
}
```

Comment: Getexternalstorage in sense getting path of device internal storage right

Comment: @Saikumarreddy2391 I have tried in Android only with external storage..You may please update and try

Comment: What if i try to create a directory that already there in path and there some files in it. does all files in that directory will lost or there wont be any change

Comment: what if user press clear cache of the application does all the data is lost

Comment: @Saikumarreddy2391 the existing files will be retained in the folder. clear cache doesn't clear the files from external storage. Have you executed the code in your device?

Comment: what is checkper in Your code is it really needed or flutter will handle the permissions required

Comment: @Saikumarreddy2391 you have to check the external storage permission. flutter will not handle

Comment: i dont know why ui is strucking i dont know why its happening i have done same as u said.i will explain shortly what i done first i promt user to select the the type file to download and then they select and then i will check if the files present in the app desired location then i will show them Tick mark symbol or i will show download symbol to say the fiel is not presnt and download it this is my code gist link https://gist.github.com/saikuamar/344ee9e8c5c1ddf5258e2e9670be7dce

Answer (score 1):

To create a Directory of App in Internal Storage use this snippet:

```
        Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String fileName =
            "xyz.pdf";
        String newPath = "";
        print(directory);
        List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
        for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
          String folder = paths[x];
          if (folder != "Android") {
            newPath += "/" + folder;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        newPath = newPath + "/YourAppName";
        directory = Directory(newPath);

        if (!await directory.exists()) {
          await directory.create(recursive: true);
        }
        if (await directory.exists()) {
          final File file = File(directory.path + "/$fileName");
          // your logic for saving the file.
        }
```

For a Detailed Explanation check out this Medium Article by Retroportal Studio:
https://retroportalstudio.medium.com/saving-files-to-application-folder-and-gallery-in-flutter-e9be2ebee92a